# alert completion not fully working

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uialertcontroller

I have an alert and right after the alert is shown, I would like to present a different viewFinder. The doSomething() function is fired, "TEST" is printed, but the new viewfinder is not presented. What am I missing?

Alert

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "Booked out.",
preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:
UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: self.doSomething)
```

content func doSomething()

```
print("TEST")
let details = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewLimo2")
details?.transitioningDelegate = slideAnimatorRight
present(details!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Is the app crashing after you try to present?

Comment: No, it didnt crash, didnt even show an error. It just ignores the present view controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The completion block on a view controller **doesn't fire when the view controller is dismissed**.  It fires when the view controller finishes presenting (e.g. it has finished with `viewDidAppear`).

Honestly, I'd expect this to crash, since you're attempting to present while the alert is still presenting.

In any case, you need to wait until the dismissal of the `UIAlertController` before you try to present the next View Controller.

You could do it in the handler for the `OK` action:

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "Booked out.",
                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:
        UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: doSomething))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

...

func doSomething(action:UIAlertAction) {
    /// present the next VC here
}
```

Comment: Thanx! :) and also thanx for the fix - worked perfectly.